Display Boot Logs Alongside Plymouth Splash Screen During Boot on Ubuntu
Display Boot Logs Alongside Plymouth Splash Screen During Boot on Ubuntu
I have installed this splash screen on Ubuntu, https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1462682, i wanted to show Boot logs alongside the splash screen, preferably on the bottom-center of the screen.
This is the only guide i was able to find online - https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/plymouth-create-your-own-splash-screen-with-scrolling-boot-messages/
But after following it's steps, i couldn't get it to work, splash screen loads no issue, but the text never appears.
Here's what i have tried so far -
1)
// display logs
function display_logs() {
    var logs = plymouth.get_lines();
    var text = logs.join("\n");
    plymouth.display_message(text, 0.5, 0.9); 
}

// Call the function to display logs
display_logs();


on the grub config file GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash plymouth:debug"




// automatic scrolling
function display_logs() {
    var lines = plymouth.get_lines();
    var log_text = lines.slice(-10).join("\n");  // last 10 lines
    plymouth.display_message(log_text, 0.5, 0.9);  
}

// upadatw
function update_logs() {
    display_logs();
    ply_event_loop_set_timeout(1000, update_logs);  // per sec
}

// Initialize log display
update_logs();


on the grub config file GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3"

Edits to /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions --->
_log_msg()
{
    if [ -x /bin/plymouth ]; then
      /bin/plymouth update --status="$@"
    fi
    if [ "$quiet" = "y" ]; then return; fi
    echo "$@"
}

Any help will be appreciated Thanks!!
